# Regexp capture unlimited groups

Tags: regex, capturing-group

I need a little help here.
So I have string:
`{block name="something" param1="param" param2="param"}`

it can be:

`{block name="something"}` or

`{block name="something" param1="value" sm="value" ng="value" um="param" .. and so on}`.

What I need is to capture all possible params.

What I could figure out so far is `{(?<type>[\w]+) ((?<param>[\w]+)="(?<value>[\w]+)")`, but it captures only first param - "name" :/

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the language that you're using?

Comment: try only `((?<param>[\w]+)="(?<value>[\w]+)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to use `\G`  in-order to do continuous string match. `\h` matches any horizontal whitespace character.

```
(?:^\{(?<type>\w+)|\G)\h*((?<param>\w+)="(?<value>\w+)")
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tT9hF5/2)